# Converting day of week to dates for the current month with MYSQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime

Spent a while searching and couldn't find any answers. Really simple question I hope.

In my database I have a string column dayOfWeek.

I use this to track what day of week weekly events are scheduled for. Usually I match the dayOfWeek to the current day using PHP and display the correct events.

What I want to do is show a calendar into the future which makes a list of the future dates of the weekly recurring event.

For example, if the event takes place on Tuesday, and Feb 2017 has Tuesdays on the 7th, 14th, 21st, and 28th. I'd like to use PHP to display as such.

I know strtotime() is used to do the opposite, find a day from the date, but can the opposite be done easily?

Sorry if my question is poorly worded or missing information.

Comment: So, if you have tuesday in your database, then you are looking for all dates in future when tuesday occurs or just for a given month?

Comment: @learner I would have use for both of those outputs. If I could get all dates in the future then I could constrain their output based on some variables (the next four dates, all dates for a given month, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE CASE FOR FEB 2017 TUESDAYS

```
$n=date('t',strtotime("2017-02-01")); // find no of days in this month
$dates=array();
for ($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){
     $day=date("D",strtotime("2017-02-".$i)); //find weekdays

    if($day=="Tue"){
        $dates[]="2017-02-".$i;
    }
}
print_r($dates);
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/s8wq-xx44

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
// The day of the week.
$dayOfEvent = row['day'];
// Say, you wanted the next 5 weeks. 
$numberOfWeeks = 5;
$tempDate = date(U);
$counter = 0;

do{
    $tempDate = $tempDate + 86,164;
    if(date('D', $tempDay) == 'Tue'){
        echo date('l jS \of F Y', $tempDay);
        $counter++;
    }
}while($counter < $numberOfWeeks);
```

Answer (score 1):

First try to find the date for the day in current week. After that keep adding 7 days multiples to it.

```
<?php 
    // $timestamp = now();

    for ($i=0; $i < 7; $i++) { 

        $days = $i." days";
        $t = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($days));
        $dayOfTheDay = date("D",strtotime($t));
        if ( $dayOfTheDay == day from table )
        {
            $current_date = $t;
            break;
        } 
    }

    for ($i=0; $i < 200; $i++) { 
        in this loop add 7 days to current_date
    }
 ?>
```